# Google Analytics uncertain behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I am developing a website in which I have to implement dynamic Google Analytics code. There will be different users on my site and every user will have their own GA IDS. I have implemented it and the code is coming right on the users page, but the reporting on google analytics is uncertian. The "Real Time" is not shown at all. And the custom variables which I am sending are also not coming. I have debugged through GA debugger for Chrome and it is not showing any errors.

What am I doing wrong? Can we have multiple GA codes implemented on the same domain? Would this be the problem?

Here is mu code:

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
_gaq.push(["_setAccount", **-********-*]);
 _gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "none"]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar",1,"UserID","USERID1",2]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar",2,"UserName","VALUE1",2]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar",3,"UserEmail","VALUE2",2]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar",4,"IP_Address","VALUE3",2]); 
 _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]); (function() { 
var ga = document.createElement("script"); 
ga.type = "text/javascript"; 
ga.async = true; 
ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })();
```

Is my code is wrong? Or what code would I use to handle my situation?

Comment: can u explain more better ?

Comment: Can you tell me what is confusing for you. Because I am not getting an idea what to explain more I have thought for 5 mins but not get an idea what to explain. SO can you please tell me what you want to know? Sorry :)

Comment: tracking code you use for your site is same for all pages ? means tracking id you use is common for all the pages..?

Comment: Yes, Tracking ID will be similar for all pages but it will be different for different users who will log in to my site. The users will give their Tracking ID in their account page which will be used when they are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Universal Analytics Tracking Code :**

Universal Analytics: Latest Version of Google Analytics

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

replace your `Tracking ID` with `XX-XXXXXXXX-X` and add this code to all of your site pages.

Comment: Yes I have used this code as well but of no use. This is the default code for GA I know but it is not working for me.

Comment: @AleemAhmad, can you post your page code..?..r u run website on localhost or live server ?

Comment: I am running the site on LIVE server. This is the code actually. Other code is just the user info coming from database.

Comment: @AleemAhmad, Please put this code only for test that page tracks or not..with only single text `"hello"` in your page `body` just for tracking.